# Android getParcelableExtra deprecated in api 33

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, deprecated, parcelable

I want to use intent method for get uri from another activity, but  intent.getParcelableExtra is deprecated.if I use

```
  if (SDK_INT >= 33) {
    
        intent.getParcelableExtra("EXTRA_URI", Uri::class.java).let { ueray ->
                timeLineView.post({
                    if (ueray != null) {
                        setBitmap(ueray)
                        videoView.setVideoURI(ueray)
    
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        else {
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
       intent.getParcelableExtra<Uri>("EXTRA_URI").let { ueray ->
                timeLineView.post({
                    if (ueray != null) {
                        setBitmap(ueray)
                        videoView.setVideoURI(ueray)
    
                    }
                })
    
            }
        }
```

this code can google play reject my app? because when in remove (SDK_INT >= 33)  statement it shows
Call requires API level 33 (current min is 21): android.content.Intent#getParcelableExtra. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No, **Google will not reject your app** if you use deprecated method, especially when using it is a necessity as you have no other choice than to use it on SDK's < 33.

My app uses deprecated methods on lower SDK's when it is an only possibility and the app is fine and accessible on the Google Play Store:

```kotlin
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    val vibrationEffect = VibrationEffect.createWaveform(
        longArrayOf(1000, 1000),
        intArrayOf(255, 0),
        0
    )

    vibrator.vibrate(vibrationEffect, vibrationAudioAttributes)
} else {
    // deprecated but working on lower SDK's
    vibrator.vibrate(longArrayOf(0, 1000, 1000), 0, vibrationAudioAttributes)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are extension functions for `Intent` and they are backward compatible:

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
inline fun <reified P : Parcelable> Intent.getParcelable(key: String): P? {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        getParcelableExtra(key, P::class.java)
    } else {
        getParcelableExtra(key)
    }
}

@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
inline fun <reified P : Parcelable> Intent.getParcelableArrayList(key: String): ArrayList<P>? {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        getParcelableArrayListExtra(key, P::class.java)
    } else {
        getParcelableArrayListExtra(key)
    }
}
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
inline fun <reified P : Parcelable> Bundle.getParcelableValue(key: String): P? {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        getParcelable(key, P::class.java)
    } else {
        getParcelable(key)
    }
}

@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
inline fun <reified P : Parcelable> Bundle.getParcelableArrayListValue(key: String): ArrayList<P>? {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        getParcelableArrayList(key, P::class.java)
    } else {
        getParcelableArrayList(key)
    }
}
```

Comment: Beware, the new functions throw an NPE for API 33. Best to use them only for API 34 and above: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240585930#comment6

Comment: Nice to see a fellow countryman here @AlvinDizon. I think you are referring to `BundleCompat` and `IntentCompat` which already handle the checking internally thus this answer is no longer practically needed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the uri put uri.toString() as an extra string.

Quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

[androidx.core:core-ktx](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core) provides `IntentCompat` class, with the following method:

```kotlin
IntentCompat.getParcelableExtra(intent, "EXTRA_URI", Uri::class.java)
```

To make it more convenient, you can create an extension:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> Intent.parcelable(key: String): T? =
    IntentCompat.getParcelableExtra(this, key, T::class.java)
```